# Where can I find my MainActivity.java when running a Android simulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I just mad my first React native project and I'm trying to lock my screen orientation to landscape. I installed this package

https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#configuration

with `npm install react-native link react-native-orientation` and now I need to

> Implement onConfigurationChanged method in MainActivity.java

So this code

```
import android.content.Intent; // <--- import
import android.content.res.Configuration; // <--- import

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  ......
  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
    intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

  ......

}
```

But where can I find that? From what I've seen is that you can find it in a android studio project. But I don't have a project, I just go to the AVD manager to run my virtual device. So where am I supposed to add this code?

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: yes, I am using expo

Answer (score 0):

The whole aim of `expo` is to handle everything related to `android` or `ios` for you.

Thus, you won't have access to these two folders **unless** you `eject` your app from `expo` as it's explained [here on the official doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/).

However, if your goal is to handle screen orientation, `expo` has a [built-in API for you that you may find here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/).

Or even simpler, you could just update your `app.json` and add this line:

```
"expo": {
   ...
   "orientation": "landscape"
   ...
}
```

Have a look at [the official doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#orientation) if you want to see everything that you can handle with this configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look via this directory:

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com
```